What was the monk in ZeroRanger going to say after "a God who wanted to become..."?
In ZeroRanger, right before being cut off by Erasure, there's a monk who claims to be a "manusya", and he says he'll offer some wisdom to the player, saying:

What was he going to say? In an older version of the game, in the intro, the premise used to be that the main character wanted to become the "Final Boss", is this a reference to that? Is the answer just "ZeroRanger"?
If so, what does that even mean, for a God to want to be a Final Boss or to be ZeroRanger?

It could be a reference. If it's not though, you're probably not going to get an answer, as there'd be no way to know unless the answer had been made public.

The Monk's story is continued through the text shown during ZeroRanger's TLB sequence, where he talks of what you see--the Lotus Jewel, a.k.a. the jewel that birthed the universe, being used to power and pilot a ZeroRanger known as the Primeval Fighter. It is literally a god that became a ZeroRanger, much like the intro text implies for "a fighter".
To corroborate this, look no further than the boss rush wheel in the Monk's stage. Each of the six bosses represent a different path of being in Buddhism. The icon for Despair (the final boss in 2-4), whom Erasure calls the pilot of the Primeval Fighter, is situated in the "deva" part of this wheel, meaning godlike. So, Despair and the Lotus Jewel are likely one and the same: two godlike final bosses.

That makes a lot of sense, the pilot of the Primeval Fighter (a fighter like the player's own ship) had originally set out to annihilate all life in the universe, and therefore was making herself the last living thing anything going up against her would face; literally a final boss. It was only after a very long time that she decided to go back and seek revenge on humanity, which is where the player starts out in the main timeline - and she was the last boss there, too. So "a god who wanted to become the final boss" is the right answer!
